# Why KeyPressEventArgs's e.Handled does nothing in KeyPressEventArgs C#?

Tags: c#, key-events

This code ( Found through internet ) seems like does nothing at all. How can I prevent non-numeric characters in my *TextBox*

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress( object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e )
{ 
   if( !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) )  
      e.Handled = true;
}
```

What's the actual purpose of *e.Handled*? Explanation needed.

Comment: If the event is not handled, it will be sent to the operating system for default processing. Set Handled to true to cancel the KeyPress event.

Comment: tell us exact problem you face

Comment: There are already lot of posts showing how to make textbox accept only numeric input.

Comment: @vnikhil I Know, but my question is why e.handled seems like does nothing.

Comment: @PranavPatel whats that does not seem like canceling the KeyPress event.

Comment: debug and check is it executed or not

Comment: @Pranav No its not executing the break point.

Comment: ya that's why it is not working...check the condition which is executed

Comment: I checked you code and it's working perfectly fine. Accepts only numeric characters. As I mentioned in another answer's comment and here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326442, You should in fact be using keypress if you want to handle key strokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to prevent non-numeric characters in TextBox then only 1 line is sufficient to handle the event

```
e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
```

Comment: Its the same as mine. My question is why we need e.Handled at all as it seems like does nothing.

Comment: bro it works perfectly even i used this syntex in many of my projects

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: What a mistake. Post really deserves -1. :) No offence please.

Comment: @vnikhil Its not about -1 or +1. I clarified some information and found out one of my mistake. And I ll not make it in future. Most of the things said, No offense, really means it. :P

Answer (score 3):

See the [MSDN: KeyEventArgs.Handled Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx):

> true to bypass the control's default handling; otherwise, false to
>   also pass the event along to the default control handler.

What you want is the `SuppressKeyPress`

```
e.SuppressKeyPress = !(e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57);
```

A different way to prevent non numeric characters is to try using Regex on

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[^0-9]"))
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Non numeric character detected.");
          textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
      }
}
```

You can also refer this [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06bba4a8-64ae-40b2-a792-65273f21050e/ehandled-true-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-return-key-on-win-forms-keydown-event-handler?forum=winforms):

> The .Handled property is used to notify base classes whether or not
>   the event has been handled or whether they need to address it. It
>   doesn't communicate that a keystroke has been handled between
>   keydown/keyup & keypress. It also works with forms with KeyPreview
>   enabled, but only from the context of Form.KeyPress events. If you
>   have a Form.KeyPress event that sets the .Handled, the control's event
>   will be ignored. The give-away there is that KeyDown events deal with
>   a KeyEventArgs where KeyPress events deal with KeyPressEventArgs.
>
> The .SuppressKeyPress was probably added just for this reason, so
>   KeyDown events could override KeyPress events.

Answer (score 1):

with  textBox1_KeyDown

```
 e.SuppressKeyPress = !(e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57);
```

or

```
  if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
                {
                    nonnumberenter = true;
                    string abc = "Please enter numbers only.";
                    DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show(abc.ToString(), "Validate numbers", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
            }
        }
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
        {
            nonnumberenter = true;
            string abc = "Please enter numbers only.";
            DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show(abc.ToString(), "Validate numbers", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }
```

Comment: I think you should change 1st statement of answer. e.Handle = true will not work in KeyDown because this event is not designed to suppress alpha numeric inputs. If you set handled to true alpha numeric key strokes will still be passed further. Your code using SuppressKeyPress will work fine.

Comment: Then why e.Handled is used?

Comment: it will stop base classes from doing any further
handling of the event. This can be useful when you're trying to
suppress action in the base class (e.g. ignore a keystroke in
KeyDown).e.Handled = True means to cancel the event or that your handling the event in your code instead.

Comment: Might be a good idea to handle the backspace key as well, in-case the user enters the wrong number and wants to correct it: `e.SuppressKeyPress = !((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || e.KeyValue == 8);`